# Vue 3 + Swiper 9

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I want to get the height of the main slider(`product-gallery__main`) and set to the thumb(`product-gallery__thumbs`) slider's height when initializing it, but during first initialization the height of main slider is 0. So I have to get the height after a certain time after initialization, but this is not the right option.Any idea how i can fix that ?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Thumbs -->
        <swiper-container class="product-gallery__thumbs" init="false">
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
        <!-- Main -->
        <swiper-container class="product-gallery__main" thumbs-swiper=".product-gallery__thumbs" init="false">
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
            <swiper-slide>
                <img src="/img/products/detail.png" alt="" />
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
    import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
    onMounted(() => {
        // Thumbs
        const swiperThumbsEl = document.querySelector(".product-gallery__thumbs");
        const swiperThumbsParams = {
            direction: "vertical",
            spaceBetween: 32,
            slidesPerView: 2,
            on: {
                init(swiper) { },
            },
        };
        Object.assign(swiperThumbsEl, swiperThumbsParams);
        swiperThumbsEl.initialize();
        // Main
        const swiperMainEl = document.querySelector(".product-gallery__main");
        const swiperMainParams = {
            direction: "horizontal",
            spaceBetween: 32,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            on: {
                afterInit(swiper) {
                    swiperThumbsEl.el.style.height = swiper.offsetHeight + "px";
                },
            },
        };
        Object.assign(swiperMainEl, swiperMainParams);
        swiperMainEl.initialize();
    });
</script>
```